How can I solve this error with the toutube-download-cli library?
The error occurs when I install the library with the command pip install youtube-download-cli and run the following command in the terminal youtube-download-cli “https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd_3EkGr0-4” mp3, for example.
The terminal output returns an error: command not found.

Either you don't have an executable called youtube-download-cli or it's not in your PATH

You really used “ and ”?

I tested the library and it seems to work fine.
The below was mentioned in their github page and pypi page (https://pypi.org/project/youtube-download-cli/)  :

This tool was tested on MacOS and Ubuntu, and probably won't work on Windows.

So if you aren't from windows then read below:
Here's somethings that might have cause you this error and some fixes:

It might just be that you didn't properly installed the library. Try to reinstall and see if you get any errors
It might be that you need to close and reopen a new terminal to start using the package, this sometimes occurs, so just try to open another CLI and try the command again.
Make sure your python related paths are correctly inside PATH environmental variable.

There is nothing really wrong with the library i just tested it on an Google Colab Env, not sure what might causes you this as there are so many cases i cannot really cover it all. Above are few of the most common cases. Try them out, but they might not be able to solve the issue.

It worked on Windows 10. With the pyinstaller library something similar happened to me and I solved it with python -m PyInstaller --onefile program.py.

I see, well they said it in their own page that's why I mentioned, ah who cares my answer, if it works for you then it works, I'm glad you solved it.

It doesn't work. Tt worked with Pyinstaller, but not with youtube-download-cli

Ah, I see what you mean, well the pyinstaller is a "ibrary" to create executables, so sure it can be use to create executables, but i think youtube-download-cli is not build for windows so it might not work, why don't you try other alternative to youtube-download-cli, like "youtube-dl" being a famous one
